# SharePoint Online is not serving index.aspx file from document library on mobiles

Tags: sharepoint-online, angular2

I have created an angular app and uploaded it to the SiteAssets library of my SharePoint online site renaming index.html to index.aspx. If I open the index.aspx file on my notebook everything works as expected: The index.aspx file is served to the browser and the browser shows my angular app:

[image]

But if I open the index.aspx file in any browser on my smartphone the index.aspx file is not served to the browser but a strange looking page is served instead:

[image]

There must be some configuration switch I am missing that tells SharePoint to not server index.aspx on mobiles. Any help is much appreciated!

Best wishes
Michael